# Is there a way to break windows2k8 r2 so it will not boot?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've got an old Win2k8 R2 VM that is a bit of a bother to me and I want it gone.  I have administrator creds to the Windows machine, but I cannot get on the hypervisor where it is running (in a remote datacenter with expensive remote hands access) (I'd have ssh access to the terminal, but somewhere along the line we lost the creds) and I do not have physical access to the hypervisor - even if I had remote hands, I'd need to give them creds I don't have and I don't expect them to root the system with me.

Is there a way I can permanently disable Windows from booting up without hypervisor access?  It's an unpatchable OS that I need offline so that it doesn't become a compliance issue.  I really just need to know if there's an easy way to destroy Windows from within,  I can to it to linux easy enough  `rm -Rf /`  but I don't know of a good way to just hamstring Windows.  I'm sure I could find one by poking around, but most of these sorts of help sites help people *fix* Windows and I just want it to die.  Ideally, this would be something that I could undo once I reclaim the hardware.

Comment: Not entirely sure why this question is garnering close votes for not enough details.  I just want to break windows so it won't boot, I probably didn't need to include any of the details as to why I need to do this, but I do.  I want it to become inoperable.  Oh man, I just thought of an obvious workaround - just pull the nic on the OS.  I still would like to know the answer to this question...  But I don't care if you close it

Comment: Uh. Just to point out doing this might be a potential career ending event.

Comment: @journeyman I think leaving up an unpatchable system is worse than taking it down by an unsavory method.

Comment: Well - maybe but in most places that kinda thing is probably going to get you fired. especially if its obvious that it was you.

Comment: I would recommend putting forward a written proposal and detailed timeline to retire this server. Give your company time to migrate to another platform. Anything else is reckless and unprofessional.

Comment: @burgi I didn't say I work for a company.

Comment: And that just makes it seem even more suspect.

Answer (score 1):

> Win2k8 R2 VM

It is a Virtual Machine.

If you want it gone, just delete it.  VMware and Hyper-V both allow you to delete Virtual Machines.

You should be able to do this from the VMware Menu or the Hyper-V Menu. I see both here (two different physical computers). Password not needed for this.

That is what I would do in this case.

You can also log into the physical machine remotely and delete the machine folder or move the folder to an archive media if you wish to keep it for some reason.

If you need to access the host machine, Pogostick (Offline password reset) that might work. You can create a bootable USB or CD to reset the password. You may need to get someone at the location to assist you.

> This is a utility to reset the password of any user that has a valid
> local account on your Windows system. Supports all Windows from NT3.5
> to Win8.1, also 64 bit and also the Server versions (like 2003, 2008,
> 2012) You do not need to know the old password to set a new one. It
> works offline, that is, you have to shutdown your computer and boot
> off a CD or USB disk to do the password reset. Will detect and offer
> to unlock locked or disabled out user accounts!

[Pogostick](https://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/)

Comment: "I cannot get on the hypervisor where it is running […] and I do not have physical access to the hypervisor." – I interpret this statement as "I cannot just delete the VM". I think the OP wants to break the VM from the inside.

Comment: Seems strange to me that there is no access to the host machine in any way.

Comment: @john it is strange, I'll grant you that.  But this doesn't answer the question, if I had access to the vmware console in any way, I could easily delete the VM's but I do not have the credentials, somehow I stored the wrong ones when building this machine 5 years ago and never noticed until now

Comment: There are offline password reset tools (not finding existing passwords - just reset).  Pogostick is known to work in older machines.  https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/  I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if I've made the question super clear, I have administrator access to the windows machine, I do not have any (free) access to the hypervisor, it is in a remote datacenter.  I just want the windows machine to die. This 100% does not answer my question or even come close to helping.

Comment: Ask the people in the Remote Data Center to start the hypervisor. Otherwise you just have a kind of paper weight. You had just said remote not remote datacentre . Ask them to delete the machine.

Comment: @john asking them = paying them (a lot) to fix my mistake.  Also, I have other machines on the hypervisor and the hypervisor's nic is completely inaccessible except from one machine I control.  I am relatively certain console access to esxi 5.5 hypervisor will not let you manage it without logging in.  The hypervisor is just as much of an unpatched burden as the windows box, but at least it's not routable.

Comment: I think you are on the correct track to ask them. They should be able to help.